# SAT Grammar - Gerunds vs. Parallelism

Tags: sentence, gerunds, parallelism, errors

Hello everyone I was working on the following question:
[image]

I said the error was A, because it should be **how to preserve** right? But apparently that is not the error, I cannot seem to find any other errors.

Which one is it?

Comment: I think you could make a case for saying B is "wrong", since you could replace it by ***was** becoming* to get a valid sentence. But I can't see anything wrong with singling out A (which could be replaced by just ***preserving***, rather than ***how to preserve***).

Comment: You were correct; the error is A.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for the right choice in a test.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be perhaps that they wanted "while becoming" to be rewritten as "while she became," thus maintaining the original tense and again clarifying the subject?

Comment: No. That's ungrammatical. If you use *"how preserving"* you need a verb somewhere in that clause.

Comment: You are correct; I should have been clearer and stated that that change could be made in addition to first changing A as indicated. It then becomes, "One challenge that writer... faced was how to preserve...while she became..."

Comment: Exactly, I think the how can't be used.